# string.format not returning correct string when used with SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

desired output: Can you relate [chore one] to one of your values (such as [value one], [value two] and [ value three])? If so, how is the activity related to your value(s)?

actual output: Can you relate [null] to one of your values (such as [value one], [value two] and [ value three])? If so, how is the activity related to your value(s)? Can you relate [chore one] to one of your values (such as [null], [null] and [ null])? If so, how is the activity related to your value(s)?

query method:

```
   public String getChoreOneWValues() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    //Select
    String[] columns= {StressQuizSQLiteHelper.CHORE_ONE,StressQuizSQLiteHelper.VALUE_ONE,
            StressQuizSQLiteHelper.VALUE_TWO, StressQuizSQLiteHelper.VALUE_THREE};
    Cursor cursor=db.query(StressQuizSQLiteHelper.REC_CHOICE_TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    StringBuilder buffer=new StringBuilder();
    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        int index1=cursor.getColumnIndex(StressQuizSQLiteHelper.CHORE_ONE);
        int index2=cursor.getColumnIndex(StressQuizSQLiteHelper.VALUE_ONE);
        int index3=cursor.getColumnIndex(StressQuizSQLiteHelper.VALUE_TWO);
        int index4=cursor.getColumnIndex(StressQuizSQLiteHelper.VALUE_THREE);
        String choreOne=cursor.getString((index1));
        String value1=cursor.getString((index2));
        String value2=cursor.getString((index3));
        String value3=cursor.getString((index4));
        buffer.append(String.format("Can you relate \"%s\" to one of your values (such as %s, %s and %s)?" +
                " If so, how is the activity related to your value(s)? ", choreOne, value1,value2, value3));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return buffer.toString();

}
```

create table string:

```
private static final String CREATE__REC_CHOICE_TABLE = "create table "
            + REC_CHOICE_TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + REC_CHOICE_TABLE_NAME_UID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement not null,"
            + VALUE_ONE
            + " text,"
            + VALUE_TWO
            + " text,"
            + VALUE_THREE
            + " text,"
            + CHORE_ONE
            + " text,"
            + CHORE_TWO
            + " text,"
            + CHORE_THREE
            + " text,"
            + CHORE_FOUR
            + " text,"
            + CHORE_FIVE
            + " text,"
            + VALUE_JOURNAL_ENTRY_ONE
            + " text,"
            + VALUE_JOURNAL_ENTRY_TWO
            + " text,"
            + VALUE_JOURNAL_ENTRY_THREE
            + " text,"
            + VALUE_JOURNAL_ENTRY_FOUR
            + " text,"
            + VALUE_JOURNAL_ENTRY_FIVE
            + " text"
            + ");";
```

insert methods:

```
public long insertPersonalValues(String one, String two, String three){
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(StressQuizSQLiteHelper.VALUE_ONE, one);
    contentValues.put(StressQuizSQLiteHelper.VALUE_TWO, two);
    contentValues.put(StressQuizSQLiteHelper.VALUE_THREE, three);

    long id = db.insert(StressQuizSQLiteHelper.REC_CHOICE_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return id;

}

public long insertChores(String one, String two, String three, String four, String five){
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(StressQuizSQLiteHelper.CHORE_ONE, one);
    contentValues.put(StressQuizSQLiteHelper.CHORE_TWO, two);
    contentValues.put(StressQuizSQLiteHelper.CHORE_THREE, three);
    contentValues.put(StressQuizSQLiteHelper.CHORE_FOUR, four);
    contentValues.put(StressQuizSQLiteHelper.CHORE_FIVE, five);

    long id = db.insert(StressQuizSQLiteHelper.REC_CHOICE_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return id;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want NULLs add 'NOT NULL' to your CREATE TABLE

Comment: Why are you blaming `String.format()` for the problem of your 4 values being `null`? That has nothing to do with `String.format()`.

Comment: I see no code inserting values, or any proof that records exist with non-null values.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano added not null. now I get an empty string as output. I don't know how these null values got inserted into my database.

Comment: It seems to me, that values and chores are saved as two separate rows. That is why they fill in null values. How do I save the 'chores' under the same primary key as 'values'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an update statement to update the null values to the desired values.